# Modal to show upon redirect (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to get a modal to show upon redirect to a page.

I am following this response ([Laravel how to redirect back to boostrap modal dialog window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639364/laravel-how-to-redirect-back-to-boostrap-modal-dialog-window))

**My controller:**

```
return redirect('postings')->with('welcome_msg');
```

**My view**:

```
@if(Session::has('welcome_msg'))        
<script>
$(function() {
$('#myModal').modal('show');
});
</script>
@endif

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the modal is not showing upon pop-up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After @if(Session::has('welcome_msg')) try doing {{dd()}} to check if you actually have the session.

Comment: Enter your error message in browser console

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

@if(Session::has('welcome_msg'))        
<script>
$(function() {
$('#myModal').modal('show');
});
</script>
@endif
```

This may fix it. HTML has to load before javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not showing.  I have updated my code: return redirect('postings')->with('welcome_msg', 'hello'); to test for the session, and view to include <div class="alert alert-success">{{ Session::get('welcome_msg') }}</div> before the modal <script> tag ... the message shows but the pop up doesn't

Comment: @jlim try <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>

Comment: @jlim Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your blade just before closing tag of `</ body>`

```
@if (session()->has('welcome_msg'))
    <script>
        $('#YourModalName').modal('toggle');
    </script>
@endif
```